# UIProgressView not reflecting first 0.05 of progress

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiprogressview

It seems to me that when setting a `UIProgressView`s progress to a value between >0.0 and 0.05 always shows a progress of 0.05 (no matter the value).

I understand that this makes sense from a UX perspective, but does `UIProgressView` have a property to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the `PlayGround` below and from @Rohan Bhale's comment, `UIProgressView` scales it's progress layer according to the view's frame size. The smaller the width, the less difference you will see at small `.progress` ranges.

At 200 points width (as depicted below), there are in fact noticeable differences in your 0 .. 0.05 range.

[image: Progress]

Comment: @I think it might be a matter of relative sizes. If we zoom or create progress view with larger size, we might notice the smallest changes.

Comment: In the end, you could always make your own progress-view by simply using 2 animated CAShapeLayers, as I did in this project: https://github.com/Bajocode/ContourProgressView